# Import Issue while trying to load JavaFX class in Jython

Tags: python, jython

I have sample Jython code for JavaFX like this:

```
# hello.py
from javafx.application import Application
from javafx.scene import Scene
import javafx.scene.control
from javafx.scene.layout import AnchorPane

class Hello(Application):
    def start(self, stage):
        stage.setTitle("Hello, World!")

        root = AnchorPane()
        label = javafx.scene.control.Label("Hello, World!")
        root.getChildren().add(label)

        scene = Scene(root, 100, 40)
        stage.setScene(scene)

        stage.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application.launch(Hello().class, [])
```

Here, I can do `import javafx.scene.control` and later use it like `javafx.scene.control.Label("Hello, World!")` but why can't I do `from javafx.scene.control import Label`?

Here's Jython info:

```
$ jython
Jython 2.5.3 (2.5:c56500f08d34+, Aug 13 2012, 14:48:36)
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.8.0_25
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move your `from`/`import` statement inside of your `start` method, immediately before you need the `Label` control, I bet your code will work.

With Jython running on JavaFX8, there are certain things that you cannot do (such as import controls) until the JavaFX runtime has been started.  (JavaFX2 was not this picky.)  For this reason, starting the JavaFX runtime is the very first thing your Jython/JavaFX program should do.  (I have a module specifically for doing this.)  *Then* you can import everything else.

As an aside, I do not think you want to use the `from`/`import` approach, but rather the `import`/`as` approach.  The former defeats caching, while the latter does not.

Comment: I wonder if you can show how you do "starting the JavaFX runtime is the very first thing..."?

I have tried a couple of things and can not get it to work.

Comment: @pablaasmo, sounds like a new question!